# Why are the last 2 lines outputting what they are?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

Can someone help me understand

1. Is this statement correct:  `BaseClass bcdc = new DerivedClass();` which means bcdc is of type BaseClass class, and its value is of type DerivedClass object? Also, what does that mean and why would an object be instantiated like that as opposed to having the class type be the same as the new object being instantiated, as in `DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass()`?
2. Why `bcdc.Method1() => Derived-Method1`. Is it because the keyword override is used, and is  so overriding the virtual Method1?
3. Why `bcdc.Method2() => Base-Method2`. I am confused because the new key word in the DerivedClass should be hiding Base-Method2? I thought that was the functionality of the new keyword.

````
class BaseClass  
{  
    public virtual void Method1()  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Base - Method1");  
    } 
    public void Method2()  
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Base - Method2");  
} 
}  
  
class DerivedClass : BaseClass  
{  
    public override void Method1()  
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Derived - Method1");  
}  
    public new void Method2()  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Derived - Method2");  
    }  
}
class Program  
{  
    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();  //bc is of type BaseClass, and its value is of type BaseClass
        DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();  //dc is of type DerivedClass, and its value is of type DerivedClass
        BaseClass bcdc = new DerivedClass();  //bcdc is of type BaseClass, and its value is of type DerivedClass.
                     
        bc.Method1();  //Base - Method1 
        bc.Method2();  //Base - Method2
        dc.Method1();  //Derived - Method1
        dc.Method2();  //Derived - Method2 
        bcdc.Method1(); //Derived - Method1. ??
        bcdc.Method2(); //Base - Method2.  ??
    }   
} ```
````

Comment: Consider a drawing app.  It has a base `DrawObject` & several derived classes: `Rectangle`, `Circle` & `Line`.  The screen is managed in a `List<DrawObject> drawList`.  When a user creates a new circle on the screen, the code does something like `drawList.Add(new Circle(params));` which is effectively what you are seeing (creating a new instance of a base class and assigning it to a reference typed to being the base class.  In the `DrawObject` class, there's a method marked `virtual` called `Draw`.  Each subclass _overrides_ that method.  Drawing everything is simply looping and calling `Draw`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual - It uses the same example I did.  Also consider an app that manages a `List<Animal> pets` collection.  Subclasses could include `Dog`, `Cat` and `Bird`.  Each subclass overrides the virtual method `Speak`.  Dogs speak "woof", cats, "meow" and birds "chirp".  That's an example that's easy to create and test in a simple console app.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you for the link and explanations. I got my example from the Microsoft docs.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords
I understand overriding and the use of virtual, but am not understanding why ```bcdc.Method2();``` is outputting Base-Meth DerivedClass Method2() has the new keyword. I would expect the out put to be Dervied-Method2. Can you point me in the right direction to understand this behavior?

Comment: When you add the `new` keyword to a method like that, you are saying "yes, I understand that my base class has a method named `Method2`, but I want to have a method named `Method2` that has a different meaning.  Consider a `CowboyArtist` class that inherits from `Cowboy`.  The Cowboy class has a method named `Draw` which means _Draw your gun from your holster_.  The CowboyArtist class wants `Draw` to mean _Make a drawing_, so it tags its implementation with `new`.  The two methods have the same name, but different semantics and are not related at all.

Answer (score 0):

> which means bcdc is of type BaseClass class, and its value is of type DerivedClass object?

Yes. I would however prefer to call it a `DerivedClass` *object* with a `BaseClass` *reference*

> Also, what does that mean and why would an object be instantiated like that as opposed to having the class type be the same as the new object being instantiated, as in DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass()?

One case is when you want to call an [explicit interface method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). However, a very similar and more common case would happen if you call a method: `MyMethod(BaseClass bcdc)`.

In this simple program all types are easily known at compile time. But for larger programs this would not be the case, a method take a `BaseClass` parameter that can have a bunch of different implementations, and all the implementations might not be known when the code is compiled.

> Why bcdc.Method1() => Derived-Method1. Is it because the keyword override is used, and is so overriding the virtual Method1?

Yes, for methods marked as [virtual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) the compiler will insert a check that forwards the method call to the overridden method based on the actual *object type*, i.e. `DerivedClass`. This is sometimes called *virtual dispatch* or [*dynamic dispatch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). I.e. the method will be selected dynamically at runtime based on the **object type**.

> Why bcdc.Method2() => Base-Method2. I am confused because the new key word in the DerivedClass should be hiding Base-Method2? I thought that was the functionality of the new keyword.

Method2 is not virtual, so there will be no dynamic dispatch. So the **reference type**, i.e. `BaseClass`,  will be used to determine the called method. This is called [*static dispatch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_dispatch), i.e. the called method can be determined statically at compile time.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much. I will look into static and dynamic dispatch to further understand.